# getting a date illegal option after running a unix script

Tags: shell, date, unix

tried to run the following script in Unix to display text with dates more than 30 days old than current date

```
awk -v threshold=$(date "--date=$(date) -30day" +%Y%m%d) -F "'" '$1 < threshold' myname.dat | wc -l
```

got the following error for dates in the format 2019-02-03 in the file myname.dat

```
date: illegal option -- -
Usage: date [-u] [+format]
   date [-u] [mmddhhmm[[cc]yy]]
   date [-a [-]sss.fff]
```

How to resolve?

Comment: Because Unix did not support the date format, try to use simple format date command in Unix.

`awk -v t=$(date +%Y-%m%d) -F "'" '$1 < t' myname.dat`

Comment: thanks how do I SUBTRACT 30 days from the current date in that command awk -v t=$(date +%Y-%m%d) -F "'" '$1 < t' myname.dat

Comment: Maybe you can use **perl** to translate date time to epoch seconds format. 
For example,
`perl -e 'print time()-2592000';printf "\n"` , 2592000 is the total seconds of one month, so that command can get you the day before 30 days.

Besides, you also need to change the date format to epoch second in your myname.dat. I think this way can help you filter the date.

For more information, you can refer to this page : [link](https://solaris-scripting-judi.blogspot.com/2018/06/unix-Linux-epoch-seconds-to-date-and-date-to-epoch-seconds.html)

Comment: okay there is no other way to subtract 30 days in the command itself awk -v t=$(date +%Y-%m%d) -F "'" '$1 < t' myname.dat without having to change the date format in the file myname.dat